# OpenOffice java cast com.sun.star.comp.beans.OOoBean to com.sun.star.lang.XComponent

Tags: java, openoffice.org, openoffice-calc

I have created OOoBean instance:

***com.sun.star.comp.beans.OOoBeanooBean = new com.sun.star.comp.beans.OOoBean();***

***XComponent xComponent = ooBean.getFrame();***

---

Error:
**com.sun.star.comp.beans.NoConnectionException
    at com.sun.star.comp.beans.OOoBean.getFrame(OOoBean.java:956)**

---

Can i create com.sun.star.comp.beans.OOoBean to com.sun.star.lang.XComponent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OOBean has getFrame() method, which can be casted to XComponent.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Error: com.sun.star.comp.beans.NoConnectionException at com.sun.star.comp.beans.OOoBean.getFrame(OOoBean.java:956)